# How to get the text, not the ID number, from an external look-up field with InfoPath?

Tags: 2013, infopath, lookup-column, dropdown, data-connection

I have an InfoPath form with a drop-down list that needs to be populated with a field from an external SharePoint list. However the field is a Look-up Field and when I get it to populate the drop-down all I get are the ID numbers of the item that it is referencing.

How can I get it to grab the text or display name of that field?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step-by-step instructions on how to do just that.

Let me know if you have any questions or need help.

[Get InfoPath to display lookup column value, not ID](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/get-infopath-to-display-lookup-column-value-not-id/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a lookup field (association) on an External Content Type (ECT) then the method I use is...

1. Right Click on the field and go to External Item picker properties
2. Select the 'General' tab
3. In the 'Display Field Name:' field put the name of the target column from the database (in my case sql).